# How to negate the word using regex in url path in html ?

Tags: html, regex-negation

Hello I want to capture the url path without the language code.
For example,

```
<a href="2nd_stage_short_1.html">abc</a>
<a href="2nd_stage_short_1_sc.html">abc</a>
<a href="2nd_stage_short_1_tc.html">abc</a>
<a href="major.html">abc</a>
<a href="detail.html">abc</a>
```

And I want to capture the url without lang code...

```
<a href="2nd_stage_short_1.html">abc</a>
<a href="major.html">abc</a>
<a href="detail.html">abc</a>
```

I try to use the regex

```
\w+(?!sc|tc).html
```

on http://www.regexr.com/ but all the url path is captured. If there is any error in my regex, I would like to listen. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Regex should not be the whole solution here. Treat the task as 2 stages and write easily readable code.

1. Regex to match the contents of all href attributes `\w+.html` and assign the matches to an array.
2. Loop over the array of results, on each iteration match for _sc or _tc `_(s|t)c` to determine if they should be added to a second array that only contains "non language" page names.

The resulting code will be really easy to understand/modify in future if new language suffixes are introduced. It can be well commented because each line has one function. Ultimately your team mates/future self will appreciate the clarity when trying to understand the code.